# How can I change the format of over 100 dataframes quickly when I don't initially know the dtypes?

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I'm trying to format a lot (>100) of dataframes after reading them in using Pandas. These aren't large datasets (max file size is about 50 MB), but have varying numbers of columns (10-100) with varying column names (some are the same), that can have integer, float, datetime, or string values. The ultimate goal is to merge them into one dataframe, but before I do, I need to get the format of each column right. I'm looking to make this process faster.

Edit: Each datatype for the column is returned as an 'object'. I tried df.infer_objects() but that just returned same datatypes.

My current formatting function is

```
def format_df(df):
    '''
    Formats the dataframe in the way I want. 

    Parameters
    -----------
    df: a pandas.DataFrame - dataframe with unformatted data types

    Returns
    -----------
    df1: a pandas.DataFrame - dataframe with correct data types

    '''
    start = time.time()
    # Copy dataframe to make changes
    df1 = df.copy()

    # Format the correct data type for each column in the dataframe
    for col in df.columns:
        try:
            # Tries to convert column to datetime format
            df1[col] = df[col].map(pd.to_datetime)
            # If entire column is null, then convert to NaN instead of NaT
            if len(df1[df1[col].isnull() == True]) == len(df1[col]):
                df1[col] = df1[col].astype(object).where(df1[col].notnull(), 
               np.nan)
                df1[col] = df1[col].astype(float)
        except:
            # If it can't convert to datetime, try converting to a numeric 
            # format (int or float)
            try:
                df1[col] = df[col].map(pd.to_numeric)
            except:
                # If data is not datetime or numeric (i.e. string of
                # characters), leave as is
                df1[col] = df[col]
    end = time.time()
    print('Time to format dataframe: ', (end-start)/60)
    return df1
```

Running the function on a dataset takes between 30 seconds and 2 minutes, but since I have over 100 dataframes, the entire process takes around 30 minutes. How can I make this faster?

I'm also looking into a way to get the column datatypes before I read the file in but I'm not sure that will be faster.

Comment: When you read in the data, `pandas` should automatically handle the numeric conversions if it can be done safely (unless you tell it not to do so). Since you aren't `coercing` any errors to `np.NaN` I'd be surprised if this actually changes any types to numeric. As for the `datetime` it can be extremely slow when a format is not specified.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but since you are only returning the formatted `df` why are you copying it to begin with?

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for pointing that out. I thought it was working fine before, but you're right that no types were being changed. I fixed it and now it's working, but still taking a long time. I guess I need to figure out a way to tell pandas the datatypes as I read in the files.

Comment: @ALollz Actually, the reason that I wasn't coercing errors is because doing that forces columns with expected string values to `np.NaN` when they should remain as strings. Assuming columns have the same datatype is okay for the datasets I'm working with and that wasn't clear in my original question. I've edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: @user3471881 You're right, I don't need to make a copy, I'm just doing it to be safe.

Comment: You can speed up some stuff by just removing unnecessary processing. For example: `len(df1[df1[col].isnull() == True]) == len(df1[col])` could just become `df1[col].isnull().all()`. Also, why do you need to format the dataframes before merging? Can't you just format the merged df? (Lastly: since you are making 100's of copies "just to be safe" (there really is no need) I would just skip that part.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try soft conversion using

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit my question, but I did try this and it just returned the same data types.